# How to check some dependency before installation of an application in Android

Tags: android

I make two android application first one is installer app that download and install my application.

Now i just want to make second application that would not be install from outside installer, means before installing second application it will check that first app is installed or not, if first application is not install it will recommend that it is necessary to install first application before second application.

Please give me suggestion i am new on android

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you keep your second app as a dependency of the first app? That way, you could prompt the user to install the second application when you start the first or after having used the first for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with package name using `PackageManager`.

```
try{
     ApplicationInfo appInfo = getPackageManager()
                             .getApplicationInfo("com.abc.firstApp", 0 );
     // application exists
    } catch(NameNotFoundException nnfe ){
     // application doesn't exist
}
```

replace `com.abc.firstApp` with your first app's package name.

You can't do this during install process. You have to check this from your second app. after finish installation of second app.

Comment: Thanks for response, but it is not my solution. Actually I want to check before installation. Like some security checking before installation. Please help.

Comment: You can't do this on or before installation process.